# What is the time complexity of csv reader in Python?

Tags: python, csv, complexity-theory, reader

I was looking through the internet and could not find an answer. What is the time complexity if this csv reader down below? I know the complexity of the for-loop is O(n). To my knowledge the csv-reader creates an object from the csv file that than can be iterated over. But what is the time complexity of this creation? I would suppose it's O(n) as it should depend on the size of the file that is being read, but I'm not sure. Also, if anyone has a source for where to find the answer I'd be grateful, as I need it for my thesis.

```
with open(_filename) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        
        
        for row in readCSV:
        ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I understand, all csv_reader does is create access to the file to be read further along in the script. This should be O(1) because regardless of the file size the process should be the same, but then further along your `for` loop is O(n) as you said, so most of the complexity of this script comes from your own code.

Comment: Here's the [python 3.8 source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/csv.py)

Comment: I looked at the python 3.8 source but I am not quite sure for what I should look there. Can you maybe specify the part of the code that is relevant to me? Because as I see it, there are several topics covered there